# mysql_data_seek not working drupal7 API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to read data twice from query result resource.I had tried with following query but it doesn't work.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM test");


echo '<pre>';

print_r($result->fetchAssoc());

mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

print_r($result->fetchAssoc());
```

Just I tried to iterate result once through $result->fetchAssoc() function again I want iterate record from first row so i used mysql_data_seek but it doesn't work

How do i use `mysql_data_seek` in drupal7?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 uses PDO so the short answer is you *don't* use the deprecated `mysql_` family of functions anywhere. If you are using those functions, you're doing something wrong.

An equivalent of your code using the Drupal API:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM test")->fetchAllAssoc('p_key');

print_r($result[0]);
print_r($result[0]);
```

See [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/db-query-not-returning-anything-or-empty-drupal-7/34731#34731) for a list of the other helper methods you can use.